# Eulers method Second order differentials

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Finding the general solution of an equation. A hint and the answer is given. I started working out the solution and got equation in standard form would be y"+y'/x+y/x^2=2sin(lnx)]

$$x^2\frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}x^2}+x\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}+y=2sin(\ln x) ,x>0$$
answer is : $$c_1 sin(\ln x)+c_2cos(\ln x)-\ln x .cos(\ln x)$$
Finding the general solution of an equation. A hint and the answer is given. I started working out the solution and got equation in standard form: y"+y'/x+y/x^2=2sin(lnx)
What are the next steps to solve this question to reach the final answer?

Comment: With the word "substitution" used, perhaps it is expected to replace $x=e^t$ which transforms the equation into a linear equation with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good start:

Solve the homogeneous part first:
$$x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$
Use the ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$ to obtain:
$$x^2 \lambda(\lambda-1)x^{\lambda-2}+x\lambda x^{\lambda-1}+x^{\lambda}=0$$
$${\lambda}^2 x^{\lambda}+x^{\lambda}=0$$
$$\lambda^2+1=0$$
Solving for $\lambda$ gives the solution to the homogeneous part $y_c$:
$$y_c=c_1 x^{i}+c_2 x^{-i}$$
We can use the fact that $x^i=e^{i\ln x}$ then apply Euler's identity. Then, redefining constants, we obtain the general solution to the homogeneous part:
$$y_c=k_1\cos(\ln x)+k_2 \sin(\ln x)$$
Notice that this looks similar to the solution you were given so far. Now, to solve for the particular solution $y_p$, use [Variation of Parameters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) and use the fact that $y=y_c+y_p$.

Feel free to tell us your progress on solving this problem.

Comment: Second line after 'use the ansatz' should read

$$\lambda^{2} x^{\lambda} + x^{\lambda} = 0$$

Comment: @Mattos Thanks for pointing this typo out, i'm fixing it now.